# Check Text Size Via Command Prompt Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd, sikuli, text-size

I'm using Sikuli to do some tests which requires the computers resolution and text size to be set to a certain size.  In this case, the text size should be set as "smaller - 100%".  I'd like the computer to check to make sure this is the case before it actually wastes time attempting to run the test.

Is there a command you can type into command prompt that will tell you what the text size setting is set to?  Or another quick way of finding the information?  The only way I know of to get the information is Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display.  Using Sikuli to open up the control panel and visually check the text size wouldn't be worth the time, so I'd like a quick way of checking.

Also, I'd rather this be without any addon or anything like that.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the text size"? Which text size? The text in the console? The default system font? The text size on some unspecified web browser or application (as the size "smaller - 100%" seems to imply)? Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). ***Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule"***, though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: sorry, I figured showing how to get there showed that.  The text size for the entire account.  Where it says "Make it easier to read what's on your screen" in the control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
AppliedDPI DWord
```

This is a per user setting.

Comment: how am I supposed to enter that? If I put that exact line into cmd prompt, it will say they system cannot find the path specified.  If I remove the HKEY_CURRENT_USER and put myself in the username directory, it'll accept the command, but doesn't show anything

Comment: Why are you writing programs when you know nothing about windows. Use the `reg` command.

Comment: well, Sikuli usually doesn't require you to know a whole lot about Windows.............

Comment: `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI`. Or to get value by itself `for /f "tokens=3" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI') do echo %A` (in a batch file %A becomes %%A). `Set /a` can work with hex numbers and Windows Calculator can convert in Scientific Mode (in Win7 and later Programmer's Mode). To change `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI /t REG_DWORD /d 0x60 /f` then issue `shutdown /r` to reboot so changesare applied.